# One button for three or more actions when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Short version: I need a button to carry out three seperate actions when clicked three times.

Long version: I have one page of my site where there is a little readable introduction with illustrations. I have a button that changes the first image to a second one when clicked once. When the user has finished reading the second image, clicking the same button then navigates to a different html location, using a multiclick function.

However, I need to add a third image to the introduction. I therefore need the button to change image1 to image2 on the first click, change image2 to image3 on the second click, then navigate to the next html location on the third click.

Is this possible? All of the multiclick solutions I've seen so far only cover two events. Or they use 'onclick', which I've been advised is bad practice. Can I modify the code I already have to add a third click action (maybe changing the value of calledonetime)? Or am I going in completely the wrong direction?

Working JS code for two actions:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiclick').click(function () {
        multiclick();
    });
});

var calledonetime = false;

function multiclick() {
    if(calledonetime=== false) {
        calledonetime = true;
        var image = document.getElementById("infoscreentext");
        image.src="infoscreentext2.png"; } /* action on first click */
        else {
        window.location.href = "castleview.html"; /* action on second click */
    }
}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" div class="toshow">
      <img src="infoscreenarrows.jpg" alt="Title" />
      <img src="infoscreentext.png" id="infoscreentext" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="enterbutton">
      <input type=image id=multiclick img src="silvercogarrow.png" alt="Enter" >
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just count the clicks? `if(count === 1)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `switch`:

```
var clickCount = 0;

function clickHandler () {
  clickCount += 1;
  switch (clickCount) {
    case 1:
      // do action #1
      break;
    case 2:
      // do action #2
      break;
    case 3:
      // do action #3
      break;
  }
}
```

Or you can use an `Array`:

```
var clickCount = -1;
var actions = [];

function action1 (e) { /* prevent default, switch to image 1 */ }
function action2 (e) { /* prevent default, switch to image 2 */ }
function action3 () { /* follow hyperlink */ }

actions.push(action1);
actions.push(action2);
actions.push(action3);

function clickHandler (event) {
  clickCount += 1;
  actions[clickCount](event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say do it with three different clicks as below with css html and js

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiclick').click(function () {
        multiclick();
    });
});

var image1 = document.getElementById("infoscreentext");
var image2 = document.getElementById("infoscreentext2");
var image3 = document.getElementById("infoscreentext3");

image1 && image1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  image1.classList.add('hide');
  image2.classList.remove('hide');
});
image2 && image2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  image2.classList.add('hide');
  image3.classList.remove('hide');
});
image3 && image3.addEventListener('click', () => {
window.location.href = "castleview.html"; 
});
</script>
```

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper" div class="toshow">
      <img src="infoscreenarrows.jpg" alt="Title" />
      <img src="infoscreentext.png" class="" id="infoscreentext" alt="" />
      <img src="infoscreentext2.png" class="hide" id="infoscreentext2" alt="" />
      <img src="infoscreentext3.png" class="hide" id="infoscreentext3" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="enterbutton">
      <input type=image id=multiclick img src="silvercogarrow.png" alt="Enter" >
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and so easy but why do you use a boolean for that? I suggest using an `Integer` for that, so let's start:-

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#multiclick').click(function () {
        multiclick();
    });
});

var clickedCount = 0;

function multiclick() {

    clickedCount++;

    if(clickedCount == 1) {
        var image = document.getElementById("infoscreentext");
        image.src="infoscreentext2.png"; /* change image on first click */
        var calledonetime[1]; 
    } /* add 1 count to calledonetime */
    else if(clickedCount == 2) {
        var image = document.getElementById("inforscreentext2");
        image.src="infoscreentext3.png"; } /* change image on second click */
    else {
        window.location.href = "castleview.html"; /* action on third click */
    }
}
</script>
```